# Closing a Web automation program when driver is not constructed

Tags: c#, selenium-chromedriver

I have a Chrome automation that sometimes fails to initialise due to Driver Timeout. Increasing the timeout is an option but there is no hard limit as to how large the timeout should be. So, I have no choice but to make sure that the program closes when there is a timeout or any other error while driver creation.

Currently, I am creating the driver like this

```
IWebDriver ChromeIns = null;

try
{
    ChromeIns = new ChromeDriver();
    // Work
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    throw ex;
}
finally
{
    if (ChromeIns != null)
    {
        ChromeIns.Quit();
    }
}
```

Currently, if the `new ChromeDriver()` fails, `ChromeIns` remains `null`. But, even though the program terminates in Visual Studio, the command window keeps running along with an open Chrome Window. This Chrome window is closed as soon as the command window is closed by `X` Button.

I tried to kill the `ChromeDriver.exe` process but it is not terminating the program.

Please help.